# VS 2012 TFS Source Control Explorer - Add Item to Right Click Menu

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, tfs, registry

I have written a PowerShell script that takes a single file as an argument and runs a compare to another file in the background. I'd like to be able to right click a file in Team Foundation Server's Solution Explorer, and choose that file as the argument for my script. I've done the exact same thing for files in the Windows Explorer, but I can't quite figure out how to do it for TFS.

I thought the registry items to be edited would be located at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\`, but I added an item the same way I added it to the Windows Explorer shell, to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding a key to Registry will be enough, you will need to create a Visual Studio Extension for that.

[Developing Visual Studio Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885119.aspx)

[Extend Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/vextend.aspx)

[Creating Extensions By Using the VSIX Project Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885241.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is this SO thread that shows how to do this strictly in Visual Studio using Options -> External Tools and Options->Customizing the context menu.

[Add an Item to the visual studio folder right-click menu within AddIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566315/add-an-item-to-the-visual-studio-folder-right-click-menu-within-addin)