# Can I add a TFS Power Tools command to VS 2012 Menu or context Menu?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs-power-tools

Specifically, I would like to add the option to run the (TFPT command: searchcs) - which opens the Commit History search GUI.

It would be beneficial to be able to add it in the Source Control Explorer or in the History window or even in a right-click contextMenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement a Visual Studio Extension to wrap this command line, see this thread:

[VS 2012 TFS Source Control Explorer - Add Item to Right Click Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003436/vs-2012-tfs-source-control-explorer-add-item-to-right-click-menu/26017354#26017354)

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259), and provide the link for reference. Please add the relevant content directly to your answer, as it'll prevent your answer from being invalidated to changes in the linked post.

Comment: I think you are right, I will do that next time, thanks for your time and advice