# Adding TortoiseSVN Context menus to Visual Studio Express

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, visual-studio-express

I am currently using Visual Studio Express for C# development and need to integrate Tortoise SVN to the same as context menus for External tools.

I need the following commands to be shown there.

1. Update to latest version
2. Commit
3. Cleanup
4. Merge
5. View History

Can this be accomplished?.

PS: Don't ask me to use Visual Studio Community, I am stuck with Express for now.

Edit: I already know how to add context menus to Visual studio express, here is the SO link for the same.

[Add an Item to the visual studio folder right-click menu within AddIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566315/add-an-item-to-the-visual-studio-folder-right-click-menu-within-addin)

Am just unclear on the actual SVN commands.

Edit: I found the solution for the same and have pasted that as the answer, thanks to @Patrick for the guidance.

Comment: AFAIK express doesn't allow you to install extensions.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9814d200(v=vs.100).aspx describes how to add external tools to VS 2010. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @SebastianRichter please try to link to english content instead of german.

Comment: @SebastianRichter yes you can, just substitute de-de in the URL by en-us *en-us or en-gb I guess

Comment: I think I need to edit my question a bit, I know how to add the context menus, I am unclear on the SVN commands.
The site below gives detailed examples on how that is to be done.

http://nickmeldrum.com/blog/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Patrick and also to this blog which shows up for a few seconds

http://garrys-brain.blogspot.in/2007/07/tortoisesvn-and-visual-studio.html

It is entirely possible to add TortoiseSVN commands as external tools and I have done just that using the values for each of the parameters needed for the External Tools dialogue, hopefully this will help others as well.

https://pastebin.com/L5rREjNL

```
Title   CommandLine Arguments   WorkingDir
Commit  c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:commit /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /notempfile  $(SolutionDir)

Update  c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:update /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /notempfile  $(SolutionDir)

History c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:log /path:"$(ItemPath)" /notempfile    $(ItemDir)
Diff    c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:diff /path:"$(ItemPath)" /notempfile   $(ItemDir)

Blame   c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:blame /path:"$(ItemPath)" /notempfile  $(ItemDir)

Revert  c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:revert /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /notempfile  $(SolutionDir)

Modifications   c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:repostatus /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /notempfile  $(SolutionDir)

Edit Conflicts  c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:conflicteditor /path:"$(ItemPath)" /notempfile $(ItemDir)

Resolve c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:resolve /path:"$(ItemPath)" /noquestion /notempfile    $(ItemDir)

Repository  c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:repobrowser /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /notempfile $(SolutionDir)

Project History c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:log /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /notempfile $(SolutionDir)

Add Solution    c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:import /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /notempfile  $(SolutionDir)

Branch/Tag  c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:copy /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /notempfile    $(SolutionDir)

Settings    c:\program files\TortoiseSVN\bin\tortoiseproc.exe   /command:settings /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /notempfile    $(SolutionDir)
```

Answer (score 1):

These resources should give you all the pieces to do this:

1. [How to integrate TortoiseSVN into Visual Studio](https://tortoisesvn.net/visualstudio.html)
2. [Automating TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)

It's a matter of creating context menus (which you say you know how to do), and passing the right parameters to Tortoise.

Comment: Thanks, I got hold of some blog somewhere there were a few examples, will update with the correct answer so that it can save people time.